# Value at position 4 in the NgModule.imports of AppModule is not a class

Tags: angular

I am trying to use ngModel in my component and needed to add NgModule. But now I am getting this error.

[image]

The app.module.ts file:

[image]

I figured out what it was.

Apparently, putting the NgModule in the imports section was causing the error. I thought I needed it to use ngModal in another module (which was what another error said). But now that I take it out, it works fine.

Not sure why it is even there. It adds it as an import when I created the project but didn't add it to the imports section.

Comment: Can you share the `AppModule` file content where you are getting the error?

Comment: Good to see you found the answer. You should write your finding and solution as the **answer** rather than adding in the question post. And next, accept the answer (once the accept answer button is available).

Comment: to use [(ngModel)] you needn't import NgModule (is the FormsModule the only Module you need import)